# Local Storage in Android Web View doesn't work sometimes

Tags: java, javascript, android, html, android-webview

I use a local storage variable in a HTML5/Javascript game to store the highscore of the game. This is working great without any problems. But when I wrap the game in a Web View in an Android App there are sometimes problems.

So the Highscore is saved in local storage but sometimes when I close the app and start it again, the highscore got reset. But sometimes the highscore is still there?!

For example: I start the game, make a highscore, close the app, start it again, the highscore is lost, I close the app, start it again, the highscore is still lost, I close it, start it again and then the highscore is there.

The code in Java:

```
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    mywebview.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/" + mywebview.getContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/");
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Any ideas, what is causing the problems?

Comment: r u using sqlite databases..!!

Comment: I'm using Local Storage just like this in Javascript: localStorage.highscore (...)

Comment: My assumption is that when you are debugging, the web viewer you are creating is volatile and does not retain anything from the previous sessions. When you don't do a clean rebuild it works, when you build fresh it starts over.

Comment: But I force close the app each time and start it again and then there is sometimes this bug. The app is also installed on my device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use now SharedPreferences as a workaround to store my highscores via a Javascript Interface. This is working great.

Comment: meh! It doesn't answer the question :/